# How to draw route in map view While user continously moving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dictionary, mapkit

I am working on an App where I need to draw the route on the Map based on user motion, continuously. I've searched for it but dint get any satisfactory solution. Need help on this !

Comment: Look at [Apple's Breadcrumb sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048).

Answer (score -1):

see this link hope might be useful

**https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes**

or use this code

`NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude] autorelease],nil];
    NVPolylineAnnotation *annotation = [[[NVPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithPoints:points mapView:map] autorelease];
    [map addAnnotation:annotation];
    [loc release];`